# jQuery toggle works after an animation but not before it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, toggle

there Stack Overflow community. I'm sure there's just something simple that I am missing but for the life of me I cannot figure out what it is.

I have a simple animation that is just transposing some divs. The animation runs and everything but I am getting some weird behaviour that I am not sure exactly why it is.

In my jQuery, there is a method `show_dots`(integer milliseconds). The only thing this function does is to call $.toggle() on the 4 elements that I am animating. I would like the function to behave like this. The page is loaded, the 4 elements are not visible. They become visible and then the animation runs.

When I include a method call to show_dots before the animation, the dots do not appear and the animation runs(I opened up the dev tools of the browser and I can see the values changing). Just for the hell of it, I threw in a method call to show dots AFTER the animation.

In that case, the behaviour was... the page loaded (the dots were visible), the animation ran, and then the dots disappeared after the method call. I'm not certain why this is the behaviour.

I've also tried animating the capacity to no avail. I'm not sure why it isn't working but I'm not sure where to start. I'm sure it's just some inherent feature that I'm unaware of, but thus far, I'm not sure what it is

Code is as follows:

```js
let tl = $("#square-animation-div-tl");
let tr = $("#square-animation-div-tr");
let bl = $("#square-animation-div-bl");
let br = $("#square-animation-div-br");

$(window).on('load', function() {
  animation_loop(1300, tl, tr, bl, br);
  $("#journey-link").on("click", pause_animation);
});

function show_dots(dur) {
  tl.toggle(250);
  tr.toggle(250);
  bl.toggle(250);
  br.toggle(250);
};

function animation_loop(dur, tl, tr, bl, br) {
  //toggle_dots(250) //this line does not make the dots toggle in or out
  tl.animate({
      left: ($("#journey-link").width() - 18),
      borderRadius: "50%",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      top: ($("#journey-link").height() - 18),
      borderRadius: "0%",
      backgroundColor: "#0000ff"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      left: -12,
      borderRadius: "50%",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      top: -12,
      borderRadius: "0%",
      backgroundColor: "#0000ff"
    }, dur);

  tr.animate({
      top: ($("#journey-link").height() - 18),
      borderRadius: "50%"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      right: ($("#journey-link").width() - 18),
      borderRadius: "0%"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      top: -12,
      borderRadius: "50%"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      right: -12,
      borderRadius: "0%"
    }, dur);

  bl.animate({
      bottom: ($("#journey-link").height() - 18),
      borderRadius: "50%"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      left: ($("#journey-link").width() - 18),
      borderRadius: "0%"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      bottom: -12,
      borderRadius: "50%"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      left: -12,
      borderRadius: "0%"
    }, dur);

  br.animate({
      right: ($("#journey-link").width() - 18),
      borderRadius: "50%",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      bottom: ($("#journey-link").height() - 18),
      borderRadius: "0%",
      backgroundColor: "#0000ff"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      right: -12,
      borderRadius: "50%",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    }, dur)
    .animate({
      bottom: -12,
      borderRadius: "0%",
      backgroundColor: "#0000ff"
    }, dur);
  toggle_dots(250);
  //animation_loop(dur,tl,tr,bl,br);
};
```

```css
.square-animation-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.square-animation-div {
  height: 24px;
  max-height: 24px;
  min-height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  max-width: 24px;
  min-width: 24px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

#square-animation-div-tl {
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#square-animation-div-tr {
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  background-color: white;
}

#square-animation-div-bl {
  bottom: -12px;
  left: -12px;
  background-color: white;
}

#square-animation-div-br {
  bottom: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square-animation-container">
  <div id="square-animation-div-tl" class="square-animation-div">

  </div>
  <div id="square-animation-div-tr" class="square-animation-div">

  </div>
  <div id="square-animation-div-bl" class="square-animation-div ">

  </div>
  <div id="square-animation-div-br" class="square-animation-div ">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pass a function reference to jQuery `toggle` function, which will be called when the toggle finished. Start your animation in that callback. Check doc for more [details](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)